# How to insert pictures without scaling?

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

I'm trying to insert two figures side-by-side, following this example from the wikibook:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gull}
                \caption{A gull}
                \label{fig:gull}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}
                \caption{A tiger}
                \label{fig:tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mouse}
                \caption{A mouse}
                \label{fig:mouse}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures of animals}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
```

I want to add my pictures without any scaling, so I put `[scale=1]` after `\includegraphics`. I would like to know what I should put after `\begin{subfigure}[b]` instead of `{0.3\textwidth}`.

Comment: Since you have two figures side by side, `{.45\textwidth}` will probably do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please post compilable code rather than a fragment. Note that we really can't tell you what you need as we don't know how big the pictures are. So while `.45\textwidth` is a plausible guess, it assumes that the two pictures are of similar widths. If not, you'd need to adjust.

Comment: @Kevin True. But this would rescale the pictures, wouldn't it? If so, I don't wanna go through this route. While those pictures are not raster, there are some texts there that could become hard to see if scaling is used. So I made sure that both of them would fit at the original size when I created them.

Comment: No that will not scale the pictures. If the pictures are too large, you will get warnings but they won't be scaled. That just says how big a box LaTeX should make to put the picture in. It is up to you to make sure what you put into the box fits. If you have 3 figures of roughly equal width and they are to go on one line `.3\textwidth` is a good guess.

Comment: By the way `scale=1` is default for `\includegraphics`. So you can just not set the width or scaling at all and the pictures won't be scaled.

Comment: @cfr I see. So if, say, the first picture fits in `.45\textwith`and there some space left, such space will not be used to rescale the picture?

Comment: If you make the minipage `.45\textwidth` and the picture is, say `.4\textwidth` in width, you'll have `.05\textwidth` extra somewhere i.e. empty space within the `minipage`. It is just a box of a certain width. Likewise, if your picture is `.9\textwidth`, it will stick out of the box and TeX will complain. But it won't scale it. That's up to you. If it needs scaling, you have to say so and that is not something you can do with `minipage`.

Comment: See examples below. (Can't show this properly in a comment and trying to describe something you can *see* like this is an exercise in frustration ;).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. The `tiger` image is bigger than the `minipage`, bigger than the paper, actually. But it is shown at natural size (except that it gets chopped off because the paper isn't big enough).

[image: too large tiger]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
      \includegraphics{tiger}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Likewise, if the image's natural size is less than the width of the `minipage`, you just get empty space:

[image: small image with empty space]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
      \includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

A `minipage` is just a box to put stuff in. TeX leaves it to you to make sure it all fits. If not - if the contents is too large or (sometimes) too small, TeX will complain - it will warn you - but it won't try to fix the problem. Whether and how to do something about it is up to you.